# Error in php: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, sql

Since i am new to php, I am not sure what could be the problem:

### class.ManageUsers.php

```
<?php


include_once('class.database.php');
class ManageUsers{

    public $link;
    function _construct(){
        $db_connection =  new dbConnection();
        $this->link = $db_connection->connect();
        return $this->link;
    }
    function registerUsers($username, $password, $ip_address, $time, $date){
        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO TESTUSERS(username, password, ip_address, reg_time, reg_date ) values (?,?,?,?,?)");
        $values = array($username, $password, $ip_address, $time, $date);
        $query->execute($values);
        $counts = $query->rowCount();
        return $counts;
    }

}
$user = new ManageUsers();
echo $user->registerUsers('foo', 'foo','127.0.0.1','12:00','12-9-2013');
    ?>
```

### class.database.php

```
    <?php
    class dbConnection{
protected $db_conn;
public $db_name ='applicationdb';
public $db_user = 'root';
public $db_password = '';
public $db_host = 'localhost';
function connect(){
$this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql: host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name",$this->db_user,$this->db_password);
return $this->db_conn;
}
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Apparently `$this->link` returns a non-object, perhaps NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't you forgot another underscore in __construct method?

Answer (score 2):

You constructor is not being invoked, since the correct signature would be __construct()

Answer (score 0):

The error says what it means :

```
$this->link
```

is not an object, in

```
query = $this->link->prepare( ... );
```

because

```
$this->link = $db_connection->connect();
```

is never executed, because of the typo ( __construct with one underscore instead of two.)